AWS Lambda error: Cannot find package '@elastic/elasticsearch' imported from /var/task/index.mjs
Even after trying adding the layer of elasticsearch to my lambda, its still giving the same error.
the commands ive followed:

npm install @elastic/elasticsearch

mkdir -p my-layer/nodejs/node_modules

cp -r node_modules/@elastic my-layer/nodejs/node_modules

zip -r my-layer.zip my-layer

created a layer and then added the layer to my lambda.


stack trace:
undefined   ERROR   Uncaught Exception  {"errorType":"Error","errorMessage":"Cannot find package '@elastic/elasticsearch' imported from /var/task/index.mjs","code":"ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND","stack":["Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package '@elastic/elasticsearch' imported from /var/task/index.mjs","    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)","    at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:965:9)","    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1022:20)","    at moduleResolveWithNodePath (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:876:12)","    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1242:79)","    at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:403:12)","    at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:372:25)","    at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:249:38)","    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:39)","    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:75:36)"]}
INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 196.17 ms    Phase: init Status: error   Error Type: Runtime.ExitError
2024-04-06T07:39:53.096Z    undefined   ERROR   Uncaught Exception  {"errorType":"Error","errorMessage":"Cannot find package '@elastic/elasticsearch' imported from /var/task/index.mjs","code":"ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND","stack":["Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package '@elastic/elasticsearch' imported from /var/task/index.mjs","    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)","    at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:965:9)","    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1022:20)","    at moduleResolveWithNodePath (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:876:12)","    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1242:79)","    at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:403:12)","    at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:372:25)","    at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:249:38)","    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:39)","    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:75:36)"]}


Zipping the whole node_modules and exporting is working.
commands to follow:
zip -r my-layer.zip node_modules

